# Evaluating limit involving hypergeometric function $\lim\limits_{z\to 1^-}{}_2F_1(-a,-b,-(a+b),z)$

Tags: limits, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

The following expression involving a hypergeometric function popped out as a solution to an integral that I've been working on (via Gradshteyn and Ryzhik):

$$L(a,b)=\lim_{z\rightarrow1^-}{}_2F_1(-a,-b,-(a+b),z)$$

where $a\geq0$ and $b\geq0$ are integers and limit is taken from below.  According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), it is undefined or infinite for the negative third term (which is my case).  However, Wolfram Mathematica happily evaluates not just the limit but the expression ${}_2F_1(-a,-b,-(a+b),1)$ for seemingly all $a$ and $b$ fitting my criteria (for example, according to Mathematica, ${}_2F_1(-3,-5,-8,1)=\frac{1}{56}$ and ${}_2F_1(-4,-6,-8,1)=\frac{1}{210}$).

Now there are expressions for the values of this hypergeometric function at [argument unity on DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4), but they don't apply in my case since the third argument is negative.

What is going on here?  Is there an expression for $L(a,b)$ in my case?  Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

This is sort of related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331833/limit-involving-a-hypergeometric-function), though I don't think the technique in that answer works here (the integral in the representation involving the beta function doesn't converge).

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ always integers?  In that case ${}_2F_1(-a,-b,-(a+b),z)$ is a polynomial of degree $c = \min\{a,b\}$.  The product of Pochhammer symbols $(a)_n(b)_n$ evaluates to $0$ for all $n > c$, so the series defining the hypergeometric function terminates there.  For example, $${}_2F_1(-3,-5,-8,z) = 1-\frac{15}{8}z+\frac{15}{14}z^2-\frac{5}{28}z^3.$$  In that case, $${}_2F_1(-3,-5,-8,1) = \sum_{n=0}^{3} \frac{(-3)_n(-5)_n}{(-8)_n n!}.$$

Comment: Yes, $a$ and $b$ are always integers.  This is helpful (though looks like I got an alternating progression here, which is a pain)...

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chu-VandermondeIdentity.html), we can recast the limit in a computationally convenient form:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow1^-}{}_2F_1\left({{-a,\quad-b}\atop{-a-b}}\middle|z\right)=\frac{(\max(a,b)-a-b)_{\min(a,b)}}{(-a-b)_{\min(a,b)}}$$

Since the function is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, we choose the larger of $a$ and $b$ in the argument and the smaller one in the index, to keep the arguments as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If a,b are positive integers then the function is a polynomial.  Look at A&S (the original Handbook of Mathematical Functions) section 15.1 :
http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf
Which is apparently legitimate from SFU.